# Ember non-static Navbar

Tags: ember.js, navbar

On index route i have login form,and with `IndexController` i send data to server and in response with JWT token a receive data about user position in system!Problem for me is how to achieve different navbar ,example: for admin i want `Home Users Company` and for standard user `Home Profile`!
I only got idea to every route put like children to `Login`(i will make new), but that is very ugly solution,or something like to  information from IndexController put in part of `index.html` who is render allways(i don't now way for that)!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to change the contents of a parent route based on the state (and type) of the logged in user.

This is often done via ember services- shared data that persists for the lifetime of the application:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/applications/services/

For example, [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) provides login functionality, and a `session` service with properties that can be used to track when someone is logged in. Your navbar template could watch `session.isAuthenticated` in that example, and only render a login button when appropriate.